# How to display in TextField only double value

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got Text field which updateds a value variable to double format in onChange... I want the TextField only display the updated the value variable.. I don't want the textfield to display any string value or values which are not in double format by pressing wrong keyboard key. Even with numeric keyboard with decimal enabled we can press decimal key multiple times which I don't want to display in the TextField.

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Value'),
        onChanged: (s) {
          if (double.tryParse(s) != null)
            setState(() {
              value = double.parse(s);
            });
        },
      )
```

How can I display only parsed value in TextField?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@user8773560 was correct however RegExp for decimal number was wrong and not working so the correct answer is

```
inputFormatters: [
          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'))
        ]
```

Also answered in my other question [Regex for double numbers in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214872/regex-for-double-numbers-in-dart)

Answer (score 15):

Please add below attribute to TextFormField Widget

```
TextFormField(
 keyboardType:TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
     inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}'))
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 10):

Answer based on @delmin's answer, but allows negative numbers as well.

```
inputFormatters: [
   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'(^-?\d*\.?\d*)'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can not use `onChange` for this purpose because its called only once `TextField` has changed.

You should try this.

```
TextFormField(
     inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
     LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(12), //max length of 12 characters
     WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,//Only numbers
     BlacklistingTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,//No line break
     WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9]+.[0-9]")) //only double values
                ],
              )
```

Lear more [here](https://dev.to/rubensdemelo/flutter-formatting-textfield-with-textinputformatter-1oii) or [Official doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply... however the formater to double doesn't seems to work `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9]+.[0-9]"))`