# Regex for double numbers in dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

As from my previous question I'm trying to allow only numbers in double format into a TextField. I have looked through the whole wide web and didn't find a Regex for dart.

```
TextFormField(
        inputFormatters: [
          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'\d*\.?\d+')) //<-- useless attempt to allow double digits only
        ])
```

Comment: Check this regex `r'(^\d*\.?\d*)$'`

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks... Seems to work however if I press decimal point twice it clears the TextField. Any idea if that can be fixed?

Comment: @MidhunMP It looks like I have fixed it `r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'` Can you answer it so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: @MidhunMP Not sure if it's desired, but that RE won't work for negative numbers nor for numbers with exponents.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't need negative numbers.. Actually I don't want negative numbers in my TextField

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:**

The WhitelistingTextInputFormatter was deprecated after *v1.20.0-1.0.pre*. So use [FilteringTextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html):

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'))
```

---

**Before *v1.20.0-1.0.pre***:

You can try with:

```
WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)'))
```

And the following is a stricter version of this regex. If the user press any invalid character other than the desired format the field will get cleared.

```
WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)$'))
```

Comment: `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` has been deprecated. Use `FilteringTextInputFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 inputFormatters: [
      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9\.-]")),
      //..   1234..
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
        RegExp(r'\.\.+'),
        replacementString: '.',
      ),
      // .23
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
        RegExp(r'^\.'),
        replacementString: '0.',
      ),
      //.23423.
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
        RegExp(r'\.\d+\.'),
      ),
      // 12341234-
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'\d+-')),
      // .-
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
        RegExp(r'\.-'),
        replacementString: '.',
      ),
      // -.34
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'-\.+')),
      // 0232
      BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'^0\d+'))
    ],
```